# Loop plot to pdf but looping identical data

Tags: r, pdf

I have written a loop of several csv to plot the data and save to pdf; which is working, however for each csv, the plot on the pdf is identical. The loop is producing the correct number of plots but it is not looping through each dataset in each csv, i assume just the first csv.

`````
require(readxl)
library(tidyverse)


# have a folder in directory called (P01)
jumpfiles <- list.files(path = c('P01'),
                        pattern = '.csv',
                        recursive = T,
                        full.names = T)


for (file in jumpfiles){

  Jump.1 = read_csv(file, col_names = T, skip = 4,trim_ws = TRUE)

  # rename variable, sub frame to time
  # select columns
    Jump.1 <- select(Jump.1, c(1,))
  names(Jump.1) [1] = 'time'


  Force_Time=substr(jumpfiles, 1, nchar(jumpfiles)-7)}

    # add time
  Jump.1$time = (seq_len(nrow(Jump.1)) -1) * 0.001


# **********************************************************************
  # pdf design (what the pdf will be titled in dir)
  pdf('dual_force_trace_P01.pdf', width = 7, height = 11)
  par(mfrow=c(5,2)) #make 5x2 layout to make plots
  par(mar=c(2, 2,1.5,1)) #set margins
  par(omi = rep(.3, 4))

# **********************************************************************
  Time <- 1:nrow(Jump.1)*0.001
  Left_Force <- Jump.1[,5]*(-1)
  Right_Force <- Jump.1[,14]*(-1)


  # PDF loop 

  for (i in 1:32){
    Jump.1 = read.csv(jumpfiles[i], skip=4, header=TRUE, sep=",")


    plot(Time, Left_Force, type = "l", lty=1, ylab = "Force (N)",
         main =Force_Time[i], xlab = "Time (s)", col= "orange")
    par(new = TRUE)
    plot(Right_Force, type = "l", lty=1, col= "blue", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n",
         ylab = "", xlab = "")
          legend("topleft", c("Left_Fz", "Right_Fz"),
           col = c("orange", "blue"), lty = c(1, 1))

  }
  dev.off()

  ````[dualforcepdf][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKv3W.jpg
`````